# Jackson convert from json string to Java object results in default object

Tags: java, json, jackson

I am trying to convert json string to Java object. Everything goes fine, object is created but it's properties are not passed. This results in an empty (default) object. What am I missing?

Here is a Java object model:

```
public class LetterCounts implements Serializable {

    private String UserId;
    private int Total;
    private int UnRead;
    private int Flagged;
    private boolean Deleted;

    public LetterCounts(){
    }
    //getters and setters
}
```

Here is my code snippet:

```
ObjectMapper mapper = new ObjectMapper();
mapper.configure(DeserializationFeature.FAIL_ON_UNKNOWN_PROPERTIES, false);
T returnValue = mapper.readValue(sb.toString(), clazz);
```

Here clazz is the name of the class i need to convert to (LetterCounts in this case) sb is a StringBuilder, which is as follows:

```
{"$id":"1","UserId":"users_1","Total":30,"UnRead":13,"Flagged":17,"Deleted":false}
```

If I use gson for deserialization, it works well. But I need to use jackson converter.

Comment: What Jackson version are you using?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems to be a problem with your variable naming. Since you left out your getter- and setter-methods I assume they look like `setUserId(String UserId)`, `getUserId()`, etc.
Jackson expects (consistent to the Java naming conventions) that the fields in your JSON are named `userId`, etc. (note the lowercase!).
You can use the [JsonProperty annotation](http://fasterxml.github.io/jackson-annotations/javadoc/2.1.0/com/fasterxml/jackson/annotation/JsonProperty.html) to force your desired name (e.g. @JsonProperty("UserId")).